# Sample size required for Fisher's exact test

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, statistical-power, count-data, fishers-exact-test

I am trying to determine the sample size I need to for 80% power at 0.05 significance in a Fisher's exact test. I want to determine if there is an association between colour and group (null hypothesis = no association).

There are plenty of questions on stats.stackexchange asking something similar but either those questions do not have an answer or relate to one-sample proportions or 2x2 tables.

I cannot do a chi-squared because expected counts include values below 5.

Attached is a screenshot of my data and the R code needed to turn the data into a dataframe.

```
c("dark", "medium", "light") -> colour
c(22L, 7L, 1L) -> group1
c(0L, 11L, 19L) -> group2
```

Is it possible you could tell me the required sample size and provide R code to do the calculation?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about a sample size (how can you know some counts in cells will be below 5 without knowing a sample size already?) or want to analyze given data? What you show appears to be data rather than assumptions about proportions in two groups (or the proportion in one group and an odds ratio for the other), which you would need. Also, what are you comparing in terms of what? E.g. if you are comparing two groups in terms of a 3-level ordinal variable (dark->medium->light), that would not be a binary outcome (for which the mentioned test is intended) but rather an ordinal outcome.

Comment: Are you planning to run a new experiment, or calculating the (post-hoc) power for the experiment whose results are summarized in this table?

Comment: Using the data I have collected so far, which I have added to my question, I am trying to determine the sample size above which a difference in colour (at p = 0.05) between group1 and group2 would be detected in a Fisher's exact test. My data suggest that a sample size smaller than what I have collected would be sufficient. Ultimate aim is to check if group1 and group2 differ in colour.

Comment: To be sure your goal is clear: Do you want to use the current "running" cell frequencies to decide whether you have achieved enough power and stop or continue with collecting more data?

Comment: No calculate an effect size from my data. Then use this effect size to calculate the sample size required to detect a statistically significant difference.